# How do you implement in PHP of using LDAP Pool Connection after we set the connection properties in apache ldap.conf?

Tags: php, ldap, connection-pooling, ldapconnection

I'm new to PHP, was interested in apache LDAP connection pool topic : [LDAP Pool](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual24/mod/mod_ldap.html)

I've found several example but mostly written in Java.

Is there a sample PHP code that I can refer to, such as documentation for PHP of implementing LDAP connection pool? How should PHP call a resource manager that gets the connection from here?

```
<Location "/ldap-status">
    SetHandler ldap-status

    Require host yourdomain.example.com

    Satisfy any
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "LDAP Protected"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://127.0.0.1/dc=example,dc=com?uid?one"
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Thank you!